# Can this Roman Number to Integer converter code be shorter?

Tags: language-agnostic, roman-numerals

95 bytes currently in python

```
I,V,X,L,C,D,M,R,r=1,5,10,50,100,500,1000,vars(),lambda x:reduce(lambda T,x:T+R[x]-T%R[x]*2,x,0)
```

Here is the few test results, it should work for 1 to 3999 (assume input is valid char only)

```
>>> r("I")
1
>>> r("MCXI")
1111
>>> r("MMCCXXII")
2222
>>> r("MMMCCCXXXIII")
3333
>>> r("MMMDCCCLXXXVIII")
3888
>>> r("MMMCMXCIX")
3999
```

And this is not duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394574/code-golf-new-year-edition-integer-to-roman-numeral), this is reversed one.

So, is it possible to make that shorter in Python, or Other languages like ruby could be done shorter than that?

Comment: You can leverage the reversed solution like this. `for x in range(1,4000):if intToRoman(x)==input:break` ;)

Comment: Vote to close on the fact that you're trying to get a better code-golf solution i bet ;) not really...

Comment: Imm, I like to see various implementations and in various languages, thats all. Its my own implemenation. I believe there is many many geeks out there who can do a lot better then that. Thats why I post this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not code golf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Shortest solutions from codegolf.com

There was a "[Roman to decimal](http://codegolf.com/roman-to-decimal)" competition over at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.com) some time ago.  (Well, actually it's still running because they never end.)  A Perl golfer by the name of [eyepopslikeamosquito](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=176576) decided to win all four languages (Perl, PHP, Python, and Ruby), and so he did.  He wrote a fascinating four-part series "[The golf course looks great, my swing feels good, I like my chances](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=759963)" ([part II](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=761053), [part III](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=762180), [part IV](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=763105)) describing his approaches over at [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org).

Here are his solutions:

### Ruby, 53 strokes

```
n=1;$.+=n/2-n%n=10**(494254%C/9)%4999while C=getc;p$.
```

### Perl, 58 strokes

```
$\+=$z-2*$z%($z=10**(19&654115/ord)%1645)for<>=~/./g;print
```

He also has a 53-stroke solution, but it probably doesn't work right now:  (it uses the `$^T` variable during a few second period in 2011!)

```
$\+=$z-2*$z%($z=10**(7&$^T/ord)%1999)for<>=~/./g;print
```

### PHP, 70 strokes

```
<?while(A<$c=fgetc(STDIN))$t+=$n-2*$n%$n=md5(o²Ûö¬Ñ.$c)%1858+1?><?=$t;
```

The six weird characters in the `md5(..)` are `chr(111).chr(178).chr(219).chr(246).chr(172).chr(209)` in Perl notation.

### Python, 78 strokes

```
t=p=0
for r in raw_input():n=10**(205558%ord(r)%7)%9995;t+=n-2*p%n;p=n
print t
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I couldn't find that before, So I better accept this.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately because the codegolf.com competition never ends, you can't see what other people are doing.  It just so happens that eyepopslikeamosquito revealed his solutions elsewhere ...

Answer (score 3):

### Python - 94 chars

cheap shot :)

```
I,V,X,L,C,D=1,5,10,50,100,500
M,R,r=D+D,vars(),lambda x:reduce(lambda T,x:T+R[x]-T%R[x]*2,x,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually defining my own fromJust is smaller, a total of **98**

```
r=foldl(\t c->t+y c-t`mod`y c*2)0 --34
y x=f$lookup x$zip"IVXLCDM"[1,5,10,50,100,500,1000] --52
f(Just x)=x --12
  -- assumes correct input
```

---

Haskell gets close.

```
import Data.Maybe --18
r=foldl(\t c->t+y c-t`mod`y c*2)0 --34
y x=fromJust$lookup x$zip"IVXLCDM"[1,5,10,50,100,500,1000] --59
```

total bytes = **111**

Would be 93 if i didn't need the import for fromJust

Answer (score 0):

Adopting [a response from Jon Skeet to a previously asked similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/284898#284898):

In my custom programming language "CPL1839079", it's 3 bytes:

```
r=f
```

Comment: yeah, if there is built-in functions, its always shorter. btw, minus are not me

Comment: Your custom programming language has to be Turing-complete, or it doesn't count.  Fork over the code, and I'll un-downvote you :)

Comment: Joey: Actually, CPL1839079 is Python with gnibbler's program (replacing r with f) included in the standard libs. Not much of a deal, isn't it?