# Finding all queries in a string in a source code using grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, pattern-matching

I need to identify all queries in a php source code spread in many files under different directories.

I though about using grep and MySQL keywords to identify them. There are two ways I can differentiate queries in this source code.

1. They are always quoted in double quotes.
2. They will always have the MySQL keywords such as `insert`, `select`, `update`, `delete` and `alter`.

But there is a problem, the queries in double quotes can be spread in multiple lines. Example :

```
$newQuery = "Select username
             from 
             usertable"
```

So I need to identify `"Select username from usertable"`

But grep can not work on multiple lines.

I tried :

```
egrep -e '"(.*?)\+"' test.php | grep "select"
```

It works great for single line but again misses multiline queries.

So I tried

```
sed -e '/\"/,/\"/!d' test.php
```

It returns all the queries, But then I do

```
sed -e '/\"/,/\"/!d' test.php | grep select
```

It  returns,

```
"select
```

which is not good. I think I need to escape newlines in sed. How do I achieve this? Any other standard commands for bash will also do, such as awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using Perl:

```
perl -00ne 'print $1,"\n" while (/"((select|insert|update|delete|alter).*?)"/sig);' file
```

To get output in single line:

```
perl -00ne 'while (/"((select|insert|update|delete|alter).*?)"/sig){$x=$1;$x=~s/\n//g;$x=~s/\s+/ /g;print "$x\n";};' file
```

To get single line output using join and split:

```
perl -00ne 'print join " ",split(/\s+/,$1),"\n" while (/"((select|insert|update|delete|alter).*?)"/sig);' file
```

Comment: It does work for the sample snippet you have put. "Not working" means no output, or output not as expected?

Comment: If you read the question carefully, you will find that sed solution I tried provides exactly the same output your solutions produces. But I need the result in single line rather then multiline. Else your solution is neat and easy to understand. The output should be like : "Select username from usertable" in a single line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I often use [`perl -pe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212378/what-should-every-perl-hacker-know-about-perl-ne) instead of `sed` for some more fancy expressions.

```
cat tmp.php | \
perl -pe "s/[\n\r\s]+/ /g" | \ # remove all spaces and line breaks
perl -e '$x=join " ", (<>); print join " ", ($x =~ /".*?(?:select|alter).*?"/gi)'
```

In the last line you find all the quotes with `select` keyword and join them

Comment: Great! I skipped the last select part, redirected all the output in a file and then grepped the file with all the keywords. Its perfect, but I need to do this individually on all the files.